# Spring batch transactions when reading from db

Tags: spring-batch

I use spring batch for reading thousands of lines from one database and want to write the result to Kafka.

The source DB is **different** from the db JobRepository uses, that is the database I want to read from is different from what spring batch uses for job and step management.

I'm a little bit confused of how transaction management is working in this case. I don't want the transaction of *source* db to be opened until the chunk processing is over .
How to achieve it?

[image]

Comment: `I don't want the transaction of source db to be opened until the chunk processing is over`: What do you mean by that ? Can you elaborate please? When the chunk processing is over, the reader/processor/writer should have been called in a transaction already at that point. How do you want the transaction to be opened until the chunk processing is over? Please share your code and a simple diagram of the sequence you are looking for to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Comment: I added small diagram that depict what are main components. I want my batch job to read from remote db,process the item and write it (kafka or rest). when reading the items for chuck processing I don't want the transaction in the remote db to held open until all the items been processed.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That is not possible. The transaction boundaries are defined around an entire chunk processing (not only the read operation). The only exception to that rule is when using a paging reader, where you would have  a transaction per page.

Comment: I do use pagining to item reader but I read from different db , not the db spring batch uses to keep all it job/step data and I don't want tp transaction to db I reading from to be open the entire chunk processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `JpaPagingItemReader` , source DB needs to open a transaction when it needs to read a page data. After that, it will close the transaction immediately.

Notice that the spring batch metadata DB also need to open a transaction during processing a chunk. So as long as the source data and the spring batch metadata are stored on the different DB, your source DB will not open a transaction for the whole chunk processing period but just for the period to read a page of data.

In term of sequence diagram when processing one chunk , the blue rectangle highlights the time when the source DB open a transaction and the red rectangle is the spring batch metadata DB.

[image]

In term of source codes , you can refer to [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/d55a09165469f8a711967ac9b15a0b91349f9d5e/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaPagingItemReader.java#L190).